# Cover available height without scroll bar for outer and inner div

Tags: html, css

I have created a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/wfd8zrrv/3/) that shows the content.

```css
.container {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

.body {
   position: relative;
   height: 100%;
   width: 100%;
   margin: 0 auto;
   background-color: #F7F4F2;
   text-align: center;
}

.form {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  color: #333;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 26px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
}

.content {
  padding: 5% 5%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="form">
        <h1>Content</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

What I am failing to do is to have the `container` element to fill the available viewport and have the inner white div also stretch to the bottom with the padding respected.

I would also like to move the link to the bottom of the viewport.

Is this possible without JavaScript?

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this using flexbox?

Put `display: flex;` on `.content`
Then use `flex: 1;` on the main child div and then `height: 100vh;`.

Now you don't need all that width and height 100% styles.

Also used box-sizing: border-box so the padding doesn't mess with the size of the containers.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
  margin: 0;
}

.body {
  position: relative;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: #F7F4F2;
  text-align: center;
}

.content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  padding: 5% 5%;
}
.form {
  flex: 1;
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 50px 20px;
  color: #333;
}

.footer {
  margin-top: 26px;
  font-size: 20px;
  line-height: 26px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="body">
    <div class="content">
      <div class="form">
        <h1>Content</h1>
      </div>
      <div class="footer">
        <a href="#">This is a link</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this CSS:

```
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
}
```

You need `height: 100%;` on every parent, all the way up to html & body. Without it, the height won't be dynamic aren't going to work.

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dagda1/wfd8zrrv/3/)